# Model not storing values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, database-design

Through references I am storing values with many-to-many relationship in ParticipantAttendance,TeamAttendance table. The table has references of Participant table and Event table.

I am using Index page of ParticipantAttendance and TeamAttendance to store values.

routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :team_results do
   collection do
    put :result
   end
 end
resources :participant_results do
  collection do
   put :result
  end
end
resources :team_attendances do
  collection do
   put :attendance
  end
end

resources :participant_attendances do
  collection do
      put :attendance
  end
end
resources :groupinfos
resources :events
resources :participants
get 'results/index'
get 'attendance/index'
root "participants#index"
end
```

Before setting relationship between participants_result,team_results and participant,event. The attendance module was storing values automatically, But now it is not storing values as it was supposed to do.

event.rb :

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :selections
has_many :participants, through: :selections

has_many :groupevents
has_many :groupinfos, through: :groupevents

has_many :participant_attendances
has_many :participants, through: :participant_attendances

has_many :participant_results
has_many :participants, through: :participant_results

has_many :team_attendances
has_many :groupinfos, through: :team_attendances

has_many :team_results
has_many :groupinfos, through: :team_results

validates :name, presence: true
end
```

participant.rb:

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :selections
has_many :events, through: :selections

has_many :groupdetails
has_many :groupinfos, through: :groupdetails

has_many :participant_attendances
has_many :events, through: :participant_attendances

has_many :participant_results
has_many :events, through: :participant_results


validates :name, presence: true
validates :email,:email => true
validates :phone,presence: true,
                 numericality: true,
                 length: { :minimum => 10, :maximum => 10 }
validates :college, presence: true

def full_info
    "#{name}, Participant ID: #{id} "
end
end
```

participant_attendance.rb :

```
class ParticipantAttendance < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :participant
 belongs_to :event
end
```

participant_attendances/index.html.erb :

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h1>Listing Participant Attendances</h1>
<%= form_tag attendance_participant_attendances_path, method: :put do %>
Round 1
<%= radio_button_tag "round", 1 %>|
Round 2
<%= radio_button_tag "round", 2 %>| 
Round 3
<%= radio_button_tag "round", 3 %>|
Round 4
<%= radio_button_tag "round", 4 %>|
Round 5
<%= radio_button_tag "round", 5 %><br><br>
Present : 
<%= radio_button_tag "mark_present", "present" %>|
Absent  :
<%= radio_button_tag "mark_present", "absent" %><br><br>
<%= submit_tag "Mark Attendance" %>  
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th>Participant</th>
  <th>Events</th>
  <th>Round</th>
  <th>Status</th> 
  <th colspan="5"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% @participant_attendances.each do |participant_attendance| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag "p_ids[]", participant_attendance.id %></td>      
    <td><%= participant_attendance.participant.name %></td>
    <td><%= participant_attendance.event.name %></td>
    <td><%= participant_attendance.round %></td>
    <td><%= participant_attendance.status %></td>  
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', participant_attendance %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_participant_attendance_path(participant_attendance) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', participant_attendance, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
<% end %>
```

ParticipantAttendancesController file method:

```
def attendance
params[:p_ids]
if params[:mark_present]=="present"
  ParticipantAttendance.where(id: params[:p_ids]).update_all(status: 'Present', round: params[:round])
else
  ParticipantAttendance.where(id: params[:p_ids]).update_all(status: 'Absent', round: params[:round])
end  

redirect_to participant_attendances_url
end
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: Where is your code that actually attempts to store a value? And how did you determine that it's not working?

Comment: by using *rails db* command and then 
`select * from participant_attendances; `

Comment: uploading the code of the index page

Comment: That's the retrieval, not the create/update. We need to see how you create the record to figure out why it isn't being stored.

Comment: updated my post @RichardAE

Comment: What does the `params[:p_ids]` statement by itself do for you? And are you sure that `where(id: [params[:p_ids])` results in a non-empty set of records? Check to make sure `params[:p_ids]` has a value that you expect.

Comment: If you look at the code of index file. I have created `p_ids[ ]` to create an array to store multiple `ids` which will be accessed through `params[:p_ids]` and yes I am sure about it. But this function will be called only when submit button comes into play before that it should store all the values from participants table.

Comment: I have created Participant Result module using same code and it is working perfectly.

Comment: I'm on the same page as @lurker, and think there is something fishy about p_ids.  It seems the argument for your `check_box_tag` should be `p_ids` according to the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag.  It seems you just pass in the name of the array that the values should be assigned to.  I would throw some logging around those update statements, and then you'll know exactly what's going on there.

Comment: So you have confirmed *directly* that, in this method, `ParticipantAttendance.where(id: params[:p_ids])` does indeed return at least one result (not relying on the fact that it's the "same code used somewhere else")? In problems like this, things are often not what they seem they should be. The `update_all` is pretty straightforward and not likely to fail without good reason.

Comment: My problem is not actually passing values to the database but fetching data from it. If I remove this function and also the checkboxes and my only aim is just to fetch `participant_id` and `event_id` from *participant* and *event* tables.

The problem is when I store data in participant table and event table the values should get automatically stored in the `participant_attendances` table because it `belongs_to :participant` and `belongs_to :events`. and participant and event tables also have `many-to-many relationship` through this participant_attendance table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form was only working when I was refreshing the page after the first redirect of the form submission. I figured it out that submit button is not submitting values to controller.

but after refreshing the page it was working fine.

I disabled `turbolinks` on this form submission and it worked.